# Best method to allow an event to work on a form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, subform

in VBA I have a subform which I use on many forms; however I have a bit of code where I only want this code to work on 'one form'; so if I have the subform with a textbox in form 1, form 2 and form 3, I want the after update event to only work for form 2.

What's the best possible way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subform has a `Parent` property.  So you can check the `Name` property of the subform's `Parent`.

```vb
Dim strParent As String
strParent = Me.Parent.Name
If strParent = "form 2" Then
    ' do stuff for form 2
End If
```

Notes:

1. That code is intended for the after update event of a text box on the subform.  If the target text box is present on the parent form instead, it's simpler; just check the parent form's name directly (`Me.Name`).
2. If the subform is opened on its own, ie not as a subform to another form, `Me.Parent` will throw an error.  You would then need to trap that error and ignore it.